# client side validation. Prevent posting form

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have some textboxes in my form. Unobtrusive jquery validation works, and makes the boxes the boxes red, when invalid values are entered. However, when I click to submit the form the form is posted back to server. why?

Is it because the textboxes are not of the model declared at the top of the view?

How can i prevent posting the form?

```
    @model Dictionary<Project, List<ProjectActualCapacity>>


@{
    var model = Model.ToList();
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("ProjectActualCapacityIndex", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@for (int i = 0; i < model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(r => model[i].Key.Name)
        </td>
        @for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
            {
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(r => model[i].Value[j].Hours, new { @class = "form-control input-sm text-right" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(r => model[i].Value[j].ID)
                </td>
            }
            @Html.HiddenFor(r => model[i].Key.ID)
        }

    </tr>
}

<input type="submit" value="Set Values" class="btn btn-default" />
```

}

Comment: include the textboxes inside the form simply will do.

Comment: Some example code would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have CliventValidationEnabled and UnobstrusiveJavaScriptEnabled in your web.config, see below.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="..." onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="...">
...
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

You can try the above code for your form. The validateForm method must return true, for the form to submit, and if it returns false, the form will not submit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
 onclientclick="return false;"
```

to the button should stop posting(always, you need to add your logic in here to make optional) with the

```
 usesubmitbehaviour="false"
```

option. Also enablevalidation="false" should break it.